# Ruby - Scraping HTML : If url does not exist then skip to next

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I am currently working on a html scraper that takes a list of anime-planet url's from a text file and then loops through them, parses and stores the data in a database.

The scraper is working nicely however if I put in a large list then the chances of the url not linking to a series properly and throwing an error is quite high. I want to try make it so that IF the url does not work then it notes down the url in an array named 'error-urls' and just skips the record.

The end result being that the script finishes all working url's and returns a list of non working urls i can work with later (maybe in a text file, or just display in console).

I am currently using a rake task for this which is working quite nicely. If anyone could help me with implementing the error handling functionality it would be much appreciated. Cheers!

**scrape.rake:**

```
task :scrape => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

text = []

File.read("text.txt").each_line do |line|
  text << line.chop
end

text.each do |series|

    url = "http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/" + series

    data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    title = data.at_css('.theme').text
    synopsis = data.at_css('.synopsis').text.strip
    synopsis.slice! "Synopsis:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t"
    eps = data.at_css('.type').text
    year = data.at_css('.year').text
    rating = data.at_css('.avgRating').text
    categories = data.at_css('.categories')
    genre = categories.css('li').text.to_s
    image = data.at_css('#screenshots img')
    imagePath = "http://www.anime-planet.com" + image['src']

    anime = Series.create({:title => title, :image => imagePath, :description => synopsis, :eps => eps, :year => year, :rating => rating})
    anime.tag_list = genre
    anime.save()

end

end
```

**Small example of list.txt**

```
5-Centimeters-Per-Second
11Eyes
A-Channel
Air
Air-Gear
Aishiteru-Ze-Baby
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `open-uri`'s error handling. See [this](http://www.somethingsimilar.com/2007/08/07/openuri-exceptions-and-http-status-codes/) for more details.

```
url = "http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/" + series

begin
    doc = open(url)
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => http_error
    # bad status code returned
    // do something here

    status = http_error.io.status[0].to_i # => 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx
    puts "Got a bad status code #{status}"

    # http_error.message is the numeric code and text in a string        
end

data = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
```